# How to include --channel when I install conda packages from file?

Tags: python, conda

`PyTorch` installation gives me
`conda install pytorch torchvision -c pytorch`

Then I tried `conda.in` as a text file as follows

```
pytorch
torchvision
jupyter
gensim
numpy
matplotlib
```

`conda install --file conda.in` works

But when I add `-c` like this

```
pytorch
torchvision -c pytorch
jupyter
gensim
numpy
matplotlib
```

It raises the error

> CondaValueError: could not parse 'torchvision -c pytorch' in: conda.in

How do I get it correctly done with file installation according to the official document?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Modify your file to specify the spec correctly:

```
pytorch::pytorch
pytorch::torchvision
jupyter
gensim
numpy
matplotlib
```

A correct spec is of the form: `(channel::)name(version(build_string))`

Read [conda 4.4.0 changelog](https://github.com/conda/conda/blob/4.4.0/CHANGELOG.md) for more examples.

Comment: Thank you very much. That is a recently changes one.